# Not able to use phpmailer script for gmail

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, openssl, phpmailer

This is my `php` script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
include("../class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "x@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "1234";
$mail->From = "y@gmail.com";
$mail->Subject = "Need Invitation";
$mail->Body = "invite me!";
$mail->AddAddress("x@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
?>
```

After executing this script i am getting following error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (1)
```

I have also `ssl` enabled:
[image]

There are a lot of question which are very similar to this but didn't get any help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

to

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

SSL operates at a different level in the network model from HTTP, SMTP, etc.

You may also have to change your `SMTPSecure` setting from `'ssl'` to `'tls'`.

Comment: @AmitPal, you may also have to change your SMTPSecure setting from `'ssl'` to `'tls'`.

Comment: got this error:
`SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed: : Called Mail() without being connected Mailer Error: The following From address failed: : Called Mail() without being connected`

Comment: @AmitPal, are you sending mail using the same Gmail account for `From` that you're authenticating with, or are you trying to use a different email address as `From`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the Email -id. Please have a look.

Comment: @AmitPal, try using the same email address for `Username` and `From`. I believe that Google locks down its SMTP service to only send from the authenticated account.

Comment: Got the same error `SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: SMTP -> FROM SERVER: SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed: : Called Mail() without being connected Mailer Error: The following From address failed: : Called Mail() without being connected`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44426/discussion-between-chris-and-amit-pal)